# Bootstrap 3 and Typeahead, how to get JSON data into dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get the JSON results to populate to the input after the data is returned from the server. This is the post function I am using and it is giving me well a formed JSON string. From what I understand from the docs, the response that is returned is what should be populating to the input, but is not in my case.

```
$('#employeeSearch').typeahead({
  source:function(query, process) {
    return $.post('employee.asp', {query:query}, function(data) {
      return data;
    }, 'json');
  }
});
```

Here is the sample string being returned from the server:

```
[{"name":"Jody Masters","id":"18"}]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$.post('employee.asp', { query: query }, function(data) {

    $('#employeeSearch').typeahead({
        source: data
    });

}, 'json');
```